# Technique to write multiple columns into a single function in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below are the two methods using Spark Scala where I am trying to find, if the column contains a string and then sum the number of occurrences(1 or 0), Is there a better way to write it into a single function where we can avoid writing a method ,each time a new condition gets added. Thanks in advance.

```
 def sumFunctDays1cols(columnName: String, dayid: String, processday: String, fieldString: String, newColName: String): Column = {
sum(when(('visit_start_time > dayid).and('visit_start_time <= processday).and(lower(col(columnName)).contains(fieldString)), 1).otherwise(0)).alias(newColName) }


 def sumFunctDays2cols(columnName: String, dayid: String, processday: String, fieldString1: String, fieldString2: String, newColName: String): Column = {
sum(when(('visit_start_time > dayid).and('visit_start_time <= processday).and(lower(col(columnName)).contains(fieldString1) || lower(col(columnName)).contains(fieldString2)), 1).otherwise(0)).alias(newColName) }
```

Below is where I am calling the function.

```
sumFunctDays1cols("columnName", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-10", "mac", "cust_count")
sumFunctDays1cols("columnName", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-10", "mac", "lenovo","prod_count")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like below (Not tested yet)

```
def sumFunctDays2cols(columnName: String, dayid: String, processday: String, newColName: String, fields: Column*): Column = {
  sum(
    when(
      ('visit_start_time > dayid)
        .and('visit_start_time <= processday)
        .and(fields.map(lower(col(columnName)).contains(_)).reduce( _ || _)),
      1
    ).otherwise(0)).alias(newColName)
}
```

And you can use it as

```
sumFunctDays2cols(
  "columnName",
  "2019-01-01", 
  "2019-01-10",
  "prod_count",
  col("lenovo"),col("prod_count")
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try this , Thanks Shankar

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter to your function a list, instead of String1, String2 .. , make the parameter as a list of string.
I have implemented a small example for you:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

  val df = Seq(
    (1, "mac"),
    (2, "lenovo"),
    (3, "hp"),
    (4, "dell")).toDF("id", "brand")

  // dictionary Set of words to check

  val dict = Set("mac","leno","noname")

  val checkerUdf = udf { (s: String) => dict.exists(s.contains(_) )}

  df.withColumn("brand_check", checkerUdf($"brand")).show()
```

I hope this solves your issue. But if you sill need help, upload the entire code snippet, and I will help you with it.